# How can I pass extra arguments into 'new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");'?

Tags: ms-word, vsto, activexobject

I am opening Word from a web page in IE using Javascript as follows:

```
var objword = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
```

This works very well for me. However, I'd like to pass in some additional arguments, or set something on the objword object which is returned, which I can then access from my Word Add-in `ThisAddIn_Startup` method.

I see on the `objword` object I have full access to the object model of the Word Application, although I can't find a good place to put a string simple property.

I've considered adding a dummy style or task pane or something which would carry the information I want, and which I could remove once I'd extracted the data from it. But this seems like a bit of a hack.

I'm looking for something like the 'Tag' property which seems to crop up all over the place when working on objects in the Office Object Model world. There's no 'Tag' property available on the Word.Application object, unfortunately.

Comment: Is your goal to identify that Word was started from your web page? What kind of information do you need to pass?

Comment: I want Word to 'know' if it is being opened from an 'Edit' screen on a website, so the Add-in will then call a Web Service to grab the OpenXml to construct a document for opening on the fly.
The Add-in needs to be able to construct the URI for the Web Service call. Even a unique identifier of some kind would suffice for this.

Comment: Also a bit of a hack, but how about changing Application.Caption ?

Comment: That is an excellent idea! Post it as an answer and I'll happily upvote it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

One solution to your problem is to expose a method from your addin that you are going to call from JavaScript. A sample how this can be achieved can be found in a blog post by Andrew Whitechapel:

> **[Passing Objects to Exposed Add-in Methods](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/11/30/passing-objects-to-exposed-add-in-methods.aspx?Redirected=true)**

Comment: This is an interesting idea. However, it requires the automation client to be able to do some stuff with ComServiceOleMarshal. I'm not sure how I would do this from JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Change Application.Caption? (Hack!)

Comment: Yes, but a much simpler hack than those I was suggesting in the original question. Furthermore, the impact if it doesn't get cleaned up is purely cosmetic.

Comment: Unfortunately all Add-in events have fired by the time I have opportunity to set the Caption. I've experimented with triggering another event once the Caption has been changed but it's all very convoluted.